# phpDocumentor relative paths to css and javascript

Tags: phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

It's my first time using phpDocumentor 2 and every file in the root folder of the documentation looks fine.

Unfortunately, anything in the subdirectories (classes, namespaces and packages) doesn't look right or function properly, because they don't reference "../css/template.css" but "css/template.css". (Same problem with the JS)

Am I missing some sort of configuration issue? The demo on the phpDoc site seems to include the reference to the parent directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not configuration... may just be a bug that's cropped up while working on the beta versions.  Open an issue about it at github (https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2).